# ReteJS add class to individual node/connection

Tags: javascript, css, rete

I've just started using [ReteJS](https://retejs.org/), and the React Renderer but in Vanilla JS. While it makes setting up simple nodes and connections super easy, I'm having trouble figuring out how to add a class/color/style to a single connection or node.

So far I have had no trouble coloring all of them by doing something like:

```css
div[data-testid="node"] {
    background-color: #0D1117;
    border: 1px solid #495057;
}

span[data-testid="output-socket"] > div > div, span[data-testid="input-socket"] > div > div {
    background-color: #0D1117;
    border: 1px solid #495057;
}

svg[data-testid="connection"] > path {
    stroke: #0D6EFD;
    stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

This produces a result like so:
[image: Correctly colored connections, but its all of them]

I have tried to create extensions of the connection class:

```js
class ActiveConnection extends Classic.Connection {
    constructor(source, sourceSlot, target, targetSlot) {
        super(source, sourceSlot, target, targetSlot);
        this.data = { label: 'Label' };
    }
    getStyle() {
        return active_styles;
    }
}
```

One way I can theorize to do it would be to keep a separate list of added nodes and when I add a connection I can see which node has been added with a query selector and diff the previous list. This seems like a hacky workaround though and I don't see this working in all situations.